# Separar json para usarlo en javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo esta salida de `json`  lo que quiero saber es como separar cada objeto - *es decir: (3,2,5  etcétera)* en variables para usar esas variables en un `javascript`.

Ejemplo:

```
{
    "procede": "1",
    "status": "1",
    "statusText": "Correct",
    "Lugares": [{
        "México": "3",
        "Ecuador": "2",
        "Tijuana": "5"
    }]
}
```

este es mi ws el include es para una clase la cual tiene una funcion get_lugares y funciona ya que este web service lo e probado y si arroja los datos

```
 include('lugares_m.php');
 $lugares_m = new lugares_m();
$lista = $lugares_m->get_lugares();

$i=0;
foreach($lista as $key => $renglon){
    $arr2["$i"]=array("Mexico"=>$renglon->getMexico(),
        "Ecuador"=>$renglon->getEcuador(),
        "Tijuana"=>$renglon->getTijuana());
$i++;
}
$salida["procede"]="1";
$salida["status"]="1";
$salida["statusText"]="Correct";
$salida["Lugares"]=$arr2;
echo json_encode($salida,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
return;
```

y este es el javascript que utilizo

```
 <script>


$.ajax({
        url: 'ws_lugares.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize(),

    })
    .done(function (lugares) {
        console.log(lugares);
        if (!lugares.error) {
          let m = lugares["Mexico"];
          let e = lugares["Ecuador"];
          let t = lugares["Tijuana"];

          console.log(m+""+e+""+t)

        } else {
            $('.error').slideDown('slow');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.error').slideUp('slow');
            }, 3500);

        }
    })
    .fail(function (resp) {
        console.log(resp.responseText);
    })
    .always(function () {
        console.log("complete");
    });

        </script>
```

Comment: Si creas variables con el nombre de los países, ¿qué pasaría cuándo el servidor devuelve un país que no definiste de antemano? ¿por qué no utilizar simplemente "lugar" como la clave que almacena el lugar? Ej: `"lugares": { "lugar": "Mexico", "numero", 3 }`. Además, no se recomienda colocar valores como claves en un JSON porque dificultan el acceso a la información.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que hice fue almacenar el json en una constate llamada **json**, luego debes obtener el valor de los **Lugares** así:

```
const lugares = json.Lugares[0];
```

Aqui tienes los valores que quieres pero me imagino que eso puede variar, entonces para hacerlo dinamico obtenemos los indices de dicho objeto así:

```
const keys = Object.keys(lugares);
```

y por ultimo recorremos esos indices en un **forEach** para recorrer el objeto **Lugares** contenido en la constante **lugares** así:

```
keys.forEach(function(lugar){
  console.log(lugar+" tiene el valor de "+lugares[lugar]);
});
```

Coloque un `console.log()` para que veas como se van obteniendo los valores allí puedes setearlas a variables o como te plazca:

```js
const json = {
              "procede": "1",
              "status": "1",
              "statusText": "Correct",
               "Lugares": [
                      {
                      "México": "3",
                      "Ecuador": "2",
                      "Tijuana": "5"
                        }
                ]
              };
              
const lugares = json.Lugares[0];
const keys = Object.keys(lugares);

keys.forEach(function(lugar){
  
  console.log(lugar+" tiene el valor de "+lugares[lugar]);
});
```

**Editado:**

Si siempre son esas mismas regiones puedes acceder directamente a ellas así:

```js
const json = {
              "procede": "1",
              "status": "1",
              "statusText": "Correct",
               "Lugares": [
                      {
                      "México": "3",
                      "Ecuador": "2",
                      "Tijuana": "5"
                        }
                ]
              };
              
const regiones = json["Lugares"][0];
let mexico = regiones["México"];
let ecuador = regiones["Ecuador"];
let tijuana = regiones["Tijuana"];

console.log(mexico+" "+ecuador+" "+tijuana);
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84615/discussion-on-answer-by-david-leonardo-molina-ruiz-dav-separar-json-para-usarlo).

Answer (score 5):

Aún no es compatible en algunos navegadores pero es apto y interesante de saber que existe:

[**Asignación por destructuración**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment)

> La sintaxis de asignación por destructuración (destructuring assignment) es una expresión de JavaScript que hace posible la extracción de datos de arreglos u objetos usando una sintaxis que equivale a la construcción de arreglos y objetos literales.

```js
let json = [
  {
    "procede": "1",
    "status": "1",
    "statusText": "Correct",
    "Lugares": [
      {
        "México": "3",
        "Ecuador": "2",
        "Tijuana": "5"
      }
    ]
  }
]

let [{ "Lugares":[{ México, Ecuador, Tijuana }] }] = json;

console.log( México );
console.log( Ecuador );
console.log( Tijuana );
```

¿Se puede usar caracteres *non-ASCII* (ej. M**é**xico) en variables de JS?... [Aquí](https://mothereff.in/js-variables#M%C3%A9xico) la respuesta :)